# Expression Engine remove index.php using .htaccess not working

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, expressionengine

My client has a godaddy Virtual Dedicated Server (yes I know it sucks)....  It has WHM VPS Optimized running on it .

I am trying to remove the index.php from the urls but my server still displays 404 errors I have looked at every forum in the universe and cant get an htaccess file that works.  Here is what expression engine tells you to put use...

```
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(/index\.php|/img|/js|/css|/robots\.txt|/favicon\.ico)
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
    </IfModule>
```

I know diddly about Apache.. please help kind sirs...

Comment: Is mod_rewrite actually enabled? http://www.mostafaberg.com/2011/04/enabling-mod_rewrite-on-apache2/

Comment: Using what peter posted down below I don't think it is... I tried using your resource and got logged into the root ssh but the command "sudo a2enmod rewrite" prompts "a2enmod: command not found"... like i said I know very very little about ssh and apache just trying to get some pretty seo friendly urls here..

Comment: and the server is running apache 2.2

Answer (score 0):

Test if the htaccess is working:

```
# Redirect domain
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.yourdomain.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/google\.com" [R=301,L]
```

Or

```
# Remove the www from the URL
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Ensure you actually have content appearing when you enter /index.php :P

Once you know your htaccess is working try "$1" instead of "%{REQUEST_URI}":

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(img|admin\.php|themes|robots\.txt|index\.php|sitemap\.xml|/favicon\.ico) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Also try "/index.php?/$1" instead of "/index.php/$1"

Ensure you have set EE (Admin->General Configuration) so "Name of your site's index page" is blank.

Remember that once you do get EE to work without the index.php appearing, it can be used both ways (with and without), which is bad for SEO, so remove it like so (place before the above rewrite :)

```
# Redirect index.php Requests (prevent site showing index.php in browser address bar)
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET.*index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule (.*?)index\.php/*(.*) /$1$2 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: # Redirect domain
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.yourdomain.com$
        RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/google\.com" [R=301,L]  
___

Is not working so neither is .htaccess apparently... ugh...